# How to add registration form to custom Opencart page

Tags: opencart, opencart-module

I have a custom page in Opencart I'd like to use for a campaign, with the aim of getting people to register on the site.

My custom page is http://www.autohouseexpress.com/index.php?route=custom/helloworld

The question now is, how do I add the registration form to that page?

Do I copy the content from the registration.tpl alone?

Thank you.

Comment: registration.tpl + the relevant data in the controller

Comment: Sorry if this is a newb question, but there is a lot of content in the controller fine, how do I identify with is relevant for just the registration form? i.e. without the login side of things.

Answer (score 0):

- Open the template file of the registration page 
  `<OC_ROOT>\catalog\view\theme\<YOUR_THEME_FOLDE>\template\account\register.tpl`
- Copy the contents of the registration form into your custom template

```html
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h2><?php echo $text_your_details; ?></h2>
    <div class="content">
      <table class="form">
        ....
```

- Now you need to copy the relevant template data to your custom controller, any thing between `<?php echo bla bla bla; ?>` is relevant, just open the registration controller located in the file `<OC_ROOT>\catalog\controller\account\register.php` , find `function index()` @ `class ControllerAccountRegister` and search for the variables there (for example, you need to copy `$this->data['action']` , `$this->data['text_your_details']` and so on

Comment: Thank you Abdo.
Would it also be necessary to copy out the validation part of the register.php controller?

Comment: not necessary, just add some hidden input field `<input type='hidden' name='custom_page' value='1'>`  to the form in the custom template, check for that field in the original validation function (the one in the `ControllerAccountRegister`) and redirect to your custom page instead of the original page if there are errors